# Display interactive notifications (with buttons) via Terminal

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, command-line, bash

I'd like to let my bash shell scripts to display gui notifications with two buttons that the user can click and then execute some commands depending on the button pressed.

What options exist?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What do you have so far to do this? What language is your script? It's best to show your work so that people don't vote to close this as too broad.

Comment: A simple bash script that performs some tasks and when done shows the notification asking for an action

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) since it has far more tutorials that help a new person solve real problems and python/tk ship with all Macs and the versions have been stable for years of OS X releases.

To get started, run this command:

```
python -c "import Tkinter;Tkinter._test()"
```

If the free tutorials linked above aren't working for your needs, the professional ones on lynda and python classes like https://www.coursera.org/learn/python are fairly easy to get started with limited time or limited funds.

You could also [start from the GUI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36814/what-is-your-preferred-way-to-start-a-shell-script-from-the-gui) with [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus/) and have it call your desired bash scripts for each button that's pressed. You could then open the "app" with open -a to get things started.

Answer (score 1):

I use a small command line "alerter" to display Alerts notifications from terminal.

i code this tool, feel free to contribute : https://github.com/vjeantet/alerter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had the most success with the widely used [`terminal-notifier`](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier) command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AppleScript which can be used from the shell with osascript. It has full gui support, integrates very well with shell scripts and has a rich user base and history with plenty of tutorials to get you started. It's preinstalled on every Mac, including a complete script editor in case you like dedicated apps.

Comment: Actually i've used AppleScripts widely alongside shell script but it seem it can only show standard notifcations in Notification Center.

Comment: So with GUI notifications you don't mean a modal dialog but a Notication Center message with buttons?

Comment: Yes, like the app store's notification shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110714/mac-os-x-nsusernotificationcenter-notification-get-dismiss-event-callback

Comment: In that case, you have to use a helper app like terminal-notifier, or use AppleScriptObjC where you call Objective-C methods from AppleScript like in http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=39189

Comment: Ok, mabye it's a bit beyond my current knowledge but i'll check it out.